# TweetSheet & FacebookSheet initial text

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, twitter

I have been searching the net for a while, but can't seem to find an answer, so hopefully someone in here will know.

I am using TweetSheet & FacebookSheet for users to post their scores after a game. I have the initial text set there with some text and their score, but the user is able to edit this message, meaning they could easily write whatever score they want in there. Is there a way to stop the user from being able to edit my initial text?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have no control over the user editing your default text when using the sharing sheet. As soon as you present the sheet, the user can change the text to whatever he wants. If you must make a post with immutable content (not recommended, for the user's sake), look into making an [SLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks Kraken, I was kinda hoping there was a way, but that's cool. Thanks for your answer mate.